# Maven assembly: placing project jar in bin folder

Tags: maven

We have a `deploy.xml` file which is referenced in by the `maven-assembly-plugin` section in the `pom.xml`.

When `mvn package -DskipTests -Pdeploy` is run from the command line, it creates a zip, within which all the dependency jars are placed in the `lib` folder. It also puts the project jar itself (with the code and configuration specific to our application) into the lib.

We would like the project jar to be placed in the `bin` folder. (Have been told that that is the standard, though not sure if that is true). How do we modify our configuration to do that?

This is the relevant configuration we have in `deploy.xml` right now:

```
<assembly>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
...
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*:*</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need two dependency sets, one including the project artifact, the other including your dependencies:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>${yourgroupid}:${yourartifactid}:jar</include>
        </includes>
        <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```